# MongoDB - match against a field, and get the first records which have distinct values in another field?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for a very performant MongoDB query that will match based on a field, 'matchField', and only return the first document which has a distinct different field, 'batchId'.

Given a collection with documents like:

```
{
  "matchField": "ABC",
  "batchId": "123",
  "documentNumber": 1,
  ...rest of document
},
{
  "matchField": "XYZ",
  "batchId": "123",
  "documentNumber": 2,
  ...rest of document
},
{
  "matchField": "ABC",
  "batchId": "345",
  "documentNumber": 3,
  ...rest of document
},
{
  "matchField": "ABC",
  "batchId": "123",
  "documentNumber": 4,
  ...rest of document
},
```

For these documents, at this stage, all I need is the metadata, which will be identical based on the "batchId"

Right now I have the *functionality* I need with a query like this:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"matchField": "ABC"}},
  {"$group": {_id: "$batchId"},
     "myMetadata1": {"$first": "$myMetadata1"}
     ... get all the fields I need
  }
]);
```

This gives me the metadata I need from documents 1 and 3. I don't get document 2 because it doesn't match the matchField. I don't get document 4 because I've already gotten a document with batchId of "123".

The problem is, it is extremely unperformant. Even though I only want these 2 records, it can take several minutes when I have 20 million records (even with everything properly indexed). I believe that's because the storage engine is still working to group all 20 million records correctly and running through the $first logic for every record, even though I only care about the data for any given record that matches my query and has a distinct batchId.

Is there any way to get this behavior reasonably performant? It seems pretty simple but I'm struggling

Comment: Have you put an index on the `matchField` and `batchId` fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even with everything properly indexed

Rather than claiming correctness here, it would be beneficial to us if instead you stated what the indexes actually are. Bonus points, and even more helpful, if you share the `.explain("executionStats")` output for the operation so that we can get a definitive look at how the database is actually executing the operation.

> I believe that's because the storage engine is still working to group all 20 million records correctly and running through the $first logic for every record, even though I only care about the data for any given record that matches my query and has a distinct batchId.

That's a good guess, and I share the same suspicion. But without the aforementioned `explain` plan we are just guessing.

> I'm looking for a very performant MongoDB query ...
>
> Is there any way to get this behavior reasonably performant?

The answer here partially depends on what the definition of 'performant' is in this situation. You mention that it currently takes several minutes, what is your target duration?

Another consideration for the answer depends on other factors. Perhaps of note - how many distinct groupings (output documents) are you getting from these 20 million source documents in the collection that are being processed?

---

###### Suggestion

Along the lines of [what @ray commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77362995/mongodb-match-against-a-field-and-get-the-first-records-which-have-distinct-v#comment136385748_77362995), it's worth double checking that the this collection is indeed properly indexed for this aggregation. The goal here should be to confirm if you're taking advantage of the [optimization to return the first document of each group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#optimization-to-return-the-first-or-last-document-of-each-group).

As was already noted, the most important thing for enabling this optimization in your situation is to have the compound index of:

```
{ "batchId": 1, "matchField": 1 }
```

We can tell that we have successfully triggered the optimization in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jyNRi2Yq7UE) due to the presence of `"stage": "DISTINCT_SCAN"` in the `explain` output. The more duplicate `batchId`s you have that get collapsed by the aggregation the more beneficial I would expect this approach would be.

You also mention that you are collecting metadata via this operation while grouping. If there are only a handful of fields or the rest of the document is large (or you just wanted to try it out), you could go a step further and expand the index to have it fully [cover the operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query). This can be accomplished by appending any additional fields that you are gathering via `$first` in the `$group` stage. Using just the `myMetadata1` field referenced in the description as an example, the larger index would be:

```
{ "batchId": 1, "matchField": 1, "myMetadata1": 1 }
```

With that, the [associated `explain` output](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ssyqOqF8NBB) then drops its reference to a `"FETCH"` stage and instead has a `"PROJECTION_COVERED"` stage.

Comment: Thank you! Taking a closer look at my explain plan, my compound index was out of order for this query, and I was erroneously matching on `subdocument: {$exists: true}` which was not able to use my index and forced a FETCH stage. With the right indices and ignoring that subdocument, my query now runs in 0.1s as opposed to 60s+ that it was previously

Comment: I'd say that's a pretty good improvement!